# is it possible get List array to load horizontally in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Do I need to dump using List and just load content into a Scrollview/HStack or is there a horizontal equivalent to stack? I would like to avoid having to set it up differently, but am willing todo so if there is no alternative... it just means recoding multiple other views.

current code for perspective:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct VideoList: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
@ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: ViewModel
@State private var isRefreshing = false

var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }) {
        HStack {
        Image("Home") // set image here
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(viewModel.videos.sorted { $0.id > $1.id}, id: \.id) { video in
            NavigationLink(
            destination: VideoDetails(viewModel: VideoDetails.ViewModel(video: video))) {
                VideoRow(video: video)
                
            }
        }
        .onPullToRefresh(isRefreshing: $isRefreshing, perform: {
            self.viewModel.fetchVideos()
        })
        .onReceive(viewModel.$videos, perform: { _ in
            self.isRefreshing = false
        })
    }
    .onAppear(perform: viewModel.fetchVideos)
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)

}
}
```

Comment: Any answer would be appreciated I have no clue to how to convert to vertical while using UIKit components

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation this is the only documentation but there is no horizontal implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, List is List and it by design is vertical-only. For all horizontal case we should use `ScrollView+HStack` or `ScrollView+LazyHStack` (SwiftUI 2.0).

Anyway here is a simple demo of possible way that can be applicable in some particular cases. Prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

*Note: all tuning and alignments fixes are out of scope - only possibility demo.*

[image: demo]

```
struct TestHorizontalList: View {
    let data = Array(1...20)

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            List {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) {
                  RowDataView(item: $0)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90)) // << rotate content back
                }
            }
            .frame(height: gp.size.width)        // initial fit in screen
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))      // << rotate List
        }
    }
}

struct RowDataView: View {
    let item: Int
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0).fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            .overlay(
                Text("\(item)")
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: so I assume then Loading the array into a HStack/ScrolView would have less issues? the only problem is getting that to refresh when the user navigates to the screen

Comment: also im unable to add the data from the server into the geometry reader @asperi "Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'VideoList.ViewModel' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'"